# Anyway to restore an image (snapshot) keeping the same IP address as before?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

have a CentOS 7 Compute Engine project and from the ssh terminal rebooted the server after seeing the kernel update hadn't been applied.  Have done that before with no issues.   However, this time server is no longer accessible.   Nmap scans show all ports that should show open are filtered.  Networking/Firewall in GCE show ports are open and not restricted to any range of IP address.
Is there any alternative way to access to see what's going on?
and, IF I restore a snapshot can I restore it to the same IP address/instance that existed before?
Thanks, in advance, for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

If you reserved a static IP before you created the node, then yes you can reapply it to another node. Otherwise no -- cloud dynamic cloud environments like GCE and AWS are generally biased against resources with external static IPs. This is in part due to the overall IPv4 address space exhaustion.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the filtered ports, the issue is not on the GCE firewalls but rather in the instance configuration. It is possible that you have an adaptive firewall rule on the instance. You can find more information on [Nmap](https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-basics.html) documentation regarding why it shows as filtered.

As for getting the same IP, you can [assign a static external IP to your instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#assign_new_instance) upon creation, or if you already have an ephemeral IP, you can [promote it to a static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-ip-addresses#promote_ephemeral_ip).

If you want to restore your instance from a snapshot and preserve the existing IP, I'll recommend the following:

1. Promote the ephemeral IP of the existing instance to a static IP.
2. Edit your GCE instance, which will have now a static IP, and set the instance IP to have an ephemeral IP again.
3. The static IP that you promoted is now released from the existing instance; you now can use it to create a new instance from
   your snapshot using that static IP.